# Not able to use cd Getting fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Tags: linux, cd-command

I am using zsh on an Ubuntu 16.04

Since today I have not been able to use the cd command. Whenever I try to change my directory from the terminal I get this error `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

I took a look at my `.zshrc` to see if an alias might have changed `cd` to a `git` command, but I couldn't find any.

I was making some changes to my `.zshrc` today and I did see an error message after making those changes and reloading the shell but I ingored it and once I changed my config back to the way it was and I reloaded the shell the error/warning went away but after that I noticed that cd wasn't working.

Is there a way I can see or trace what program a unix command is hitting so that I can get to the root of this problem

EDIT: My zsh autocomplete works with cd but when I press enter I get this error.

This is the output of `which cd`

```
cd () {
    if [[ "$#" != 0 ]] && [[ "$#" != 1 ]]
    then
        git push origin "${*}"
    else
        [[ "$#" = 0 ]] && local b="$(git_current_branch)" 
        git push origin "${b:=$1}"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to check what is linked to cd with this command

```
which cd
```

If the setup is standard, you should get this message:

> cd: shell built-in command

If it's not the case then you can see what causes the problem.

If you are using oh-my-zsh, this can come from it too since it's a git-based project.

Comment: I have updated my post with the output of which cd can you please take a look @NathanJ ?

Comment: How do I set it back to the original shell command?

Comment: My bet is that this function is defined somewhere in your zshrc or by files that you include in the zshrc. You need to remove it (Or change its name depending on where it is used)

Comment: @LemmyKillmister `unset -f cd` or `unfunction cd`.

Comment: I checked my `.zshrc` this function is not there, I don't even remember writing it.

Comment: thanks so much @Kusalananda that fixed it